# Manage server unavailability in AngularJS $resource

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this code in my services.js file:

```
angular.module('appServices', ['ngResource']).
  factory('User',function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost\\:3001/api/user/:id', {}, {
      query: {method: 'GET', params: {id: id}, isArray: false},
      save: {method: 'POST', params: {id: id}, isArray: false}
    });
  });
```

It can happen that server is not available sometimes. How should I better catch and manage this case properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to handle this situation in your controller using error callback.  As per [AngularJS Documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource):

> - HTTP GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], [success],    [error])
> - non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters],    postData, [success], [error])
> - non-GET instance actions:    instance.$action([parameters], [success], [error])

Sample code:

```
...
$scope.user = User.query(
    // success callback
    function () {},
    // error callback
    function (error) {
        //Handle error here
 } )
 ...
```